# **args in function raises TypeError "takes 0 positional arguments" [python]

Tags: python

```
def f(**args):
    print(args)
```

This gives TypeError exception. Though when I pass no args, like f(). It just prints nothing.

What could be the reason and how to pass args? I tried with f( [4,5]), but still same result

Answer (score 6):

`f` only has a dictionary argument `**args` (more frequently written as `**kwargs`), which means that only keyword arguments are allowed (passing nothing at all is of course also allowed).

To enable positional arguments, add `*args`:

```
def f(*args,**kwargs)
```

or pass your parameter with any keyword:

```
f(foo=[4,5])
```

and `kwargs["foo"]` is `[4,5]` in `f`

Answer (score 2):

`**` handles *keyword arguments*. So your function indeed doesn't take any *positional arguments*, only keyword arguments (or nothing).

Positional arguments are aggregated with `*args`, conventionally keyword arguments with `**kwargs`.